# Convert array and object with HTML entities

Tags: php, arrays, object, html-entities

I am trying to write a piece of code, that will recursively convert every string in an array or object to be safe with the quotes for displaying in input boxes.

This is an array I wrote, with parts I have seen from other peoples. And it works for objects but not arrays, it seems to get to the second array, and outputs a string "null"

```
function fixQuotes($item)
{
    if (is_object($item)) {
        foreach (get_object_vars($item) as $property => $value) {
            //If item is an object, then run recursively
            if (is_array($value) || is_object($value)) {
                fixQuotes($value);
            } else {
                $item->$property = htmlentities($value, ENT_QUOTES);
            }
        }
        return $item;
    } elseif (is_array($item)) {
        foreach ($item as $property => $value) {
            //If item is an array, then run recursively
            if (is_array($value) || is_object($value)) {
                fixQuotes($value);
            } else {
                $item[$property] = htmlentities((string)$value, ENT_QUOTES);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Html encode quotes. That's all you have to do to fix your input quote issue.

Comment: That's what it does to each item, but it needs to do it to every item on the object or array.

Comment: You wrote you're converting every string to an array or object. You don't need to do that. Just apply `htmlentities` directly.

Comment: You need to do &value in order to modify array by reference: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: Every string is already on an object or array. You can't send an object or array to htmlentities. This script is attempting to go through the object or array, then send each string to htmlentities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not saving the array if it was two arrays deep, it is now working, also it was missing the return on the array. Thanks for reading it.

Here is a copy of the fixed code if someone in future needs a script that does this.

```
function fixQuotes($item)
{
    if (is_object($item)) {
        foreach (get_object_vars($item) as $property => $value) {
            //If item is an object, then run recursively
            if (is_array($value) || is_object($value)) {
                $item->$property = fixQuotes($value);
            } else {
                $item->$property = htmlentities($value, ENT_QUOTES);
            }
        }
        return $item;
    } elseif (is_array($item)) {
        foreach ($item as $property => $value) {
            //If item is an array, then run recursively
            if (is_array($value) || is_object($value)) {
                $item[$property] = fixQuotes($value);
            } else {
                $item[$property] = htmlentities((string)$value, ENT_QUOTES);
            }
        }
        return $item;
    }
}
```